# Browser for cross-site-script testing (for testing Mozilla Add-On)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, same-origin-policy

I am working on a Firefox extension that will involve ajax calls to domains that would normally fail due to the same-origin policy set by Firefox (and most modern browsers).

I was wondering if there is a way to either turn off the same-origin restriction (in about:config, perhaps) or if there was a standard lite-browser that developers turn to for this.

I really would like to avoid using any blackhat tools, if possible. Not because I'm against them, I just don't want to add another learning curve to the process.

I can use curl in PHP to confirm that the requests work, but I want to get started on writing the js that the addon will actually use, so I need a client that will execute js.

I also tried spidermonkey, but since I'm doing the ajax with jquery, it threw a fit at all of the browser-based default variables.

So, short version: is there a reliable browser/client for cross site scripting that isn't primarily a hacker app? Or can I just turn off same-domain policy in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) with [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest)

Comment: This is as good as anything. I wish it was a bit closer to the client, but this works!

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into [HTTP Access Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control)

Comment: That requires server support.